# Challenges running fastcv's loadJpeg sample

Tags: android, eclipse, image-processing, android-ndk, cygwin

I have successfully installed, and run the samples from, [Qulacomm's Vuforia](http://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/augmented-reality).
I've been trying to work around [Qualcomm's fastCV](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv) samples however for some time now but cannot manage to run the samples due to the following errors:

```
 make: *** [all] Error 2
 make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

After cleaning and building, the console reads;

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project com.qualcomm.loadjpeg.LoadJpeg ****

make all 
Host OS was auto-detected: windows
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, /<NDK-PATH>/ndk-build, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

make: *** [all] Error 2

**** Build Finished ****
```

I've followed the suggestions recommended [here](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv/developer-tips-tricks&ei=p82QUNPcC4Si0QXauYFg&usg=AFQjCNEaF3QbQoxlLrFyg2vQ1W034nB3hQ&sig2=oAi6K6c5Iaq1T03fOFd3TQ) and all the steps instructed [here](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv/compiling-and-running-fastcv-sample-app).

I've ensured to paste the fastcv folder from the `<FASTCV-PATH>/inc` directory to all the platforms in the ndk path `<NDK-PATH>\platforms\<ANDROID-VERSION>\arch-arm\usr\include` as frequently recommended online (it's only needed for the Android version of testing as far as I know, but I've placed it in all versions available just in case.

ndk-build seems to be working fine btw, below is the result upon `ndk-build` (after `cd` to project's directory)
[image]

I've already added the ndk and the make.exe paths in the PATH environment variable.
Also I've followed the suggestions to a similar problem [here](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdevnet-forums/computer-vision-fastcv/18122).

I'm using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 running on Windows 7(64-bit). The project and API files are all in the same Eclipse workspace to minimise errors.

Thank you for your time.